# Track Google AdWords clicks in Facebook iframe tab

Tags: facebook, analytics, tracking, google-ads-api

I have a google adwords campaign (search) that is targeting my Facebook iframe tab application.

Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to see clicks from campaign in Google analytics that I have set up for tab. It shows pageview and visitor, but I cannot separate if it comes from campaign or direct traffic....

I have found some workaround for setting up analytics so it can track traffic sources correctly since facebook (for its privacy) adds the s-static.ak.facebook etc.. link so it doesnt show correct traffic source.

Did anyone of you had this issue and fixed it ? It would mean a world to me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to separate organic traffic (clicks on tab happening on fanpage) and paid traffic (facebook ads or adwords campaign leading directly to the custom tab). I just finished a [blog post](http://startupinternals.wordpress.com/2012/05/09/how-to-track-campaigns-leading-to-facebook-tab/) about how to do it.